# I can't seem to understand why will the program not terminate after printing ((1)

Tags: java, data-structures

This is a binary tree function which I can't seem to understand how will it run recursively without any return functions.

```java
public class Node {
    Node left, right; int data;
    Node(int d) { data = d; }

    public void f() {
        System.out.print("(");
        if (left != null) {
            left.f();
            System.out.print("_");
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.f();
            System.out.print("_");
        }
        System.out.print(data);
        System.out.print(")");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node a = new Node(0);
        Node b = new Node(1);
        Node c = new Node(2);
        Node d = new Node(3);
        a.left = b;
        a.right = c;
        c.left = d;
        a.f(); 
    }
}
```

// ans is = ((1)_((3)_2)_0)

I tried debugging it to see step by step but still couldn't understand it at all

Comment: b--a--c
d--c

1--0--2
3--2

If you follow the code, you will get the answer that you have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant seem to understand how will it run recursively without any return functions.

Since `f()` is void, the returns are implicit and not needed to return since no value is returned.

Take pencil and paper and carefully go through the complete method and write down what is taking place, took place, etc.  Then see if it matches the following modification where I added additional print statements. You should also have tree diagram with the data and node links, including those that are null and those that aren't.

```java
public class NodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node a = new Node(0);
        Node b = new Node(1);
        Node c = new Node(2);
        Node d = new Node(3);
        a.left = b;
        a.right = c;
        c.left = d;
        a.f();
    }
}

class Node {
    Node left, right;
    int data;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("f() entered - printing open paren");
        System.out.println("(");
        
        if (left != null) {
            System.out.println("left is not null, calling left.f()");
            left.f();
            System.out.println("returned from left.f() printing underscore");
            System.out.println("_");
        } else {
            System.out.println("left was null");
        }
        if (right != null) {
            System.out.println("right is not null, calling right.f()");
            right.f();
            System.out.println("returned from right.f() printing underscore");
            System.out.println("_");
        } else {
            System.out.println("right was null");
        }
        System.out.println("printing data and closing paren");
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(")");
        System.out.println("returning from recursive call.");
    }

}
```

prints the following

```
f() entered - printing open paren
(
left is not null, calling left.f()
f() entered - printing open paren
(
left was null
right was null
printing data and closing paren
1
)
returning from recursive call
returned from left.f() printing underscore
_
right is not null, calling right.f()
f() entered - printing open paren
(
left is not null, calling left.f()
f() entered - printing open paren
(
left was null
right was null
printing data and closing paren
3
)
returning from recursive call
returned from left.f() printing underscore
_
right was null
printing data and closing paren
2
)
returning from recursive call
returned from right.f() printing underscore
_
printing data and closing paren
0
)
returning from recursive call
```